# The proof that the counting measure is actually a measure requires the countable axiom of choice?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

In my proof I use this axiom. I would like to know if this proof does not depend on the countable axiom of choice?

Comment: What is your proof?

Comment: That depends on exactly how you define $\mu(E)=\infty$.